# How to install .air files with air2beta

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, air

I have some troubles installing air files that've been built with air2.0beta or air2.0beta2
They both do not install (error message: 'your need an update to install this air application) even though I've got the latests Air2 runtime installed.
Any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I got it. Also the SDK for Air2 has been released. Using that one, I'm able to install.
http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/air2.html